# Cannot make two ajax calls in one request

Tags: php, jquery

I'm creating a user profile in php with the aid of jquery and ajax.

What the script does is it has a left navigation, which are tabs that populate the content area from requests made via ajax.

So I click a tab, it loads a page(using `.get()`), the content of the page is a form. When the form is submitted an ajax request is made to a php file that uses that data to determine what to do. Right now I haven't set up anything in the php file besides a response to send back to the DOM to know it works.

Here is the javascript related to the code in question:

```
/**
 * 
 */
$(function() {
        $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $.post(target, function(data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#flash').html(data).hide().fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
  });
});

/**
 * 
 */
$(function() {
    $('#profile-tabs > a').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $('#profile-tabs > a').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get(target, function(data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#profile-content').html(data).hide().fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
  });
});
```

When I load the tab directly without ajax, it submits just fine, the only time it doesn't work is when the content is called through the ajax request.

The javascript code I just provided is in a file called profile.js and is called after jquery.js

Any suggestions or ideas would be awesome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `$('form').on('submit' ...` with `$('body').on('submit', 'form', ...`.. I'm pretty sure, that jQuery binds the event to `$('form')` elements when the code loads - then, when you load your form using `$.get`, the event is not bound to the form.

Using the other method, it binds the even to `$('body')`, which is always there, and executes the bound function whenever the event-target is a form-element.

Comment: thank you kindly for the explanation. This has resolved my issue, kudos!